# opencv: how to change the transparency level of an image

Tags: opencv, transparency, alpha

Is it possible to change the transparency level of an IplImage (the alhpa channel)?  I can do this using cvSet and setting all the values to a cvScalar, but that would change not only the alpha channel, but the actual RGB channels, as well.

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a scalar to an RGBA image with cvAddS:

```
void cvAddS(const CvArr* src, CvScalar value, CvArr* dst, const CvArr* mask=NULL)
```

For increasing just the alpha channel of an image you could use for example a cvScalar(0,0,0,30).
This will increase the alpha value by 30.
The same way cvSubS can be applied to substract a scalar.